# How to deploy a code-first Entity Framework database using Azure Devops pipelines to SQL server

Tags: azure-devops, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-2.2

We are building an ASP.net application using Entity Framework core with Azure DevOps and targeting IIS with MSSQL server 2016.

Our test server is a local Windows 2016 machine containing both IIS and the SQL server instance.

I have successfully written a deployment workflow enabling continuous deployment on  that test server of the code itself but I can't find any way to deploy the database. The first version was targeting asp.net core 2.0 so I could use the command-line to start the application outside of IIS and trigger a database update but when we switched to 2.2 and in-process IIS deployment, we apparently lost that capability.

I would like to integrate the deployment of the database to the server in the deployment pipeline, including the DB creation, but I can't find any way to do so using Azure Devops: I can target an Azure SQL instance but, unless I'm missing something,  not a local one.

So:

- How can I manually create and populate the database using an ASP.NET core 2.2 in-process application on a machine with no SDK installed?
- What do I need to add to the Azure DevOps pipeline to deploy the database to a **local MSSQL server** database

Comment: I think this is more on-topic on [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: I don't know: it's devops so: is it more dev or more operations? The dev team is the one responsible for the pipeline, in my case.

Comment: DevOps questions should go on Software Engineering then. But most people question here on this subject.

Answer (score 2):

EDIT:
For deploying on local, I followed below two steps:

**1. Create Database Script**

You can create normal Create Database script which creates the database in the local database instance.

**2. Apply Migrations**

Create simple console application which runs the create database script first and then applies the migrations.

```
myDbContext.Database.Migrate();
```

That's how I got it working.

**Previous Contents about Publishing DB to Azure:**

You need "Azure SQL Publish" task. 
Pre requisite is you should have Azure SQL Database already created.

Steps:

*Step1 : Command To generate migration script in build pipeline*

Create a command line task to generate the migration script:

```
dotnet ef migrations script -i -o %BUILD_ARTIFACTSTAGINGDIRECTORY%\migrate.sql --project EfMigrationApp.Database\EfMigrationApp.Database.csproj --startup-project EfMigrationApp\EfMigrationApp.csproj -i -o %BUILD_ARTIFACTSTAGINGDIRECTORY%\migrate.sql
```

*Step 2: Azure SQL Publish in release pipeline*

Action: Publish
Type: SQL script file
Sql script should be as below:

```
$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)/_$(Build.DefinitionName)/drop/migrate.sql
```

Refer [this article for setting up CI pipeline](https://manojchoudhari.wordpress.com/2020/01/09/creating-first-ci-for-net-core-ef-code-first-in-azure-devops/).
Refer [this article for setting up CD pipeline](https://manojchoudhari.wordpress.com/2020/01/10/release-pipeline-for-net-core-and-ef-core-application-in-azure-devops/).

Comment: Thank you for your answer but you apparently didn't read my question properly: I'm not trying to deploy to SQL Azure, I'm trying to deploy a local SQL server instance

Comment: The only relevant difference between SQL Azure and a local instance is the `server` part of the connectionstring. So the answer provided above will work for you.