# How can I automate migrations on asp.net MVC on deployment?

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, azure-devops

I recently deployed my asp.net MVC app using IIS Deployment and my database is at the server. My question is, is there a way I can automate the migrations on the Azure Pipeline, and if so, how?

Comment: Not get your response for several days, would you please share your latest information about this issue? If you have any concern, feel free to share it here.

Answer (score 0):

For this issue ,I think you can use Azure SQL Publish task in release pipeline. The only relevant difference between SQL Azure and a local instance is the server part of the connectionstring. So this task will work for you.

Step1 : Command To generate migration script in build pipeline

Create a command line task to generate the migration script:

```
dotnet ef migrations script -i -o %BUILD_ARTIFACTSTAGINGDIRECTORY%\migrate.sql --project EfMigrationApp.Database\EfMigrationApp.Database.csproj --startup-project EfMigrationApp\EfMigrationApp.csproj -i -o %BUILD_ARTIFACTSTAGINGDIRECTORY%\migrate.sql
```

Step 2: Azure SQL Publish in release pipeline

Action: Publish Type: SQL script file Sql script should be as below:

```
$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)/_$(Build.DefinitionName)/drop/migrate.sql
```

For details ,plese refer to this [blog](https://dotnetplusplus.com/2018/09/23/deploying-a-code-first-entity-framework-database-in-azure-devops/) and [case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54253001/how-to-deploy-a-code-first-entity-framework-database-using-azure-devops-pipeline).